# Normalization of a node

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

How do you describe the normalization of $\mathrm{Spec}(k[[x,y]]/(xy))$? In particular, call this $N$. Why can $N$ be written as the intersection of 2 local rings and the same holds for the maximal ideal (with 2 maximal ideals)?

Comment: Can you see geometrically what the normalization is? Consider first the non-completed situation, $k[x,y]/(xy)$, make a picture...

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez is it something like this $k[x]\oplus k[y] $??this is not normal! I have to take $Spec(k[x])\cup Spec(k[y])$ ans normalization

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez geometrically it is easy: 2 disjoint lines. But why can I write it as intersection of 2 local rings?

Comment: @induktio: your edit substantially changed the meaning of the question. Why did you do that?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh My apologies. I meant to correct the bad phrasing and the like, not to drastically alter the substance of the question. I have changed it back mathematically to what it was before, I believe, but the grammatical changes remain.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I did in my newest edit--it has to be approved first. It will be changed though. No worries.